# How do I use a new Image() in react

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs

I am trying to keep an image from reloading when the state changes.
The below image variable is passed into the props of a custom react component.
var img = new Image();          I've already set the src, title, desc, etc.

So my question is.
In the custom react component, how do I take the image object (now a prop titled img) and display it in the render function?

I've already tried

```
render: function(){
  return <div>{this.props.img}</div>
}
```

But I keep getting a DOM elements are not valid child of React components error.

Comment: Have you tried writing the image element in as JSX? ex: `return <div><img src={this.props.img.src} title={this.props.img.title} ... /></div>` You *may* be able to write it cleaner with a spread operator: `<img {... this.props.img} />`.

Comment: This essentially just passes the string in, which causes the <img to load a new image.  I'm trying to load the image once, then reuse the one already loaded vs. loading it every time the state changes.

Comment: Here's your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67416031/2612640 -- tl;dr you can use the .outerHTML property to get the html string and combined with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop, voila.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is create a new DOMNode of the Image variety and render that as a child of the `<div>`. If that's right, you're doing something React isn't made to do. Two options:

**Option 1 (Best):** Render the image tag in your React component template

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={'url-to-your-image'} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Option 2 (Not as good):** Render the image as an HTML string entity

```
renderHTML: function() {
    return {
        __html : '<img src="url-to-your-image" />'
    }
},

render: function() {
    return (
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.renderHTML()} />
    );
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Essentially, both of these options create a new image with an `<img />` tag. That's not what the questioner wants, which is reusing an `Image` object that's already created with JavaScript.

Answer (score 8):

The `Image` constructor returns an `HTMLImageElement` interface.

So to render your `img` prop, which as you mention was created using `var img = new Image()`, you basically have to create an element and render it.

You can do this via `JSX`

```js
const YourComponent = ({img}) => <img src={img.src} alt="foo" />
```

or

Use the `React.CreateElement` syntax if you *need* to do it programmatically.

```js
const YourComponent = ({img}) => {

  const myImage = React.createElement("img", {
     src: img.src,
     // any other image attributes you need go here
  }, null);

  return (
    {myImage}
  );
}
```

Comment: new Image() hard to use except as props in React. Are there performance considerations for all `img.props` here for changes to img object? Virtual DOM mounts & does re-render (or match?) `img.props.style` changes, but not if field is defined outside of the sync func. Second option guides us to use static props like `style={{width:"100%}}` so I choose to export `class <div style={{width:maxWidth?maxWidth:"0%"}}>` wrapping {`React.createElement for import().then(img=>img.default)` & `window.URL.createObjectURL(blob), src`}, as only change's css `calc` not all `props`, which I only assume matters